# Failed: RuntimeError: Saving diagram failed! when running rake erd command

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, graphviz, erd

I am trying to rake erd to generate diagrams for models in my rails application. I am on windows 7 and graphviz is installed

When I run

```
rake erd OR rake erd filetype=dot
```

I am getting following error

```
$ rake erd --trace
** Invoke erd (first_time)
** Invoke erd:generate (first_time)
** Invoke erd:options (first_time)
** Execute erd:options
** Invoke erd:load_models (first_time)
** Execute erd:load_models
Loading application environment...
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
Loading code in search of Active Record models...
** Execute erd:generate
Generating Entity-Relationship Diagram for 6 models...
rake aborted!
Saving diagram failed!
Verify that Graphviz is installed and in your path, or use filetype=dot.
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram/graphviz.rb:198:in `r
escue in block in <class:Graphviz>'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram/graphviz.rb:190:in `b
lock in <class:Graphviz>'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram.rb:142:in `instance_e
val'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram.rb:142:in `save'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram.rb:120:in `create'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram.rb:74:in `create'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/tasks.rake:41:in `block (2 le
vels) in <top (required)>'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_c
all_chain'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain
'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prereq
uisites'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_c
all_chain'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain
```

Did any one have experience with such issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this library swallows the underlying error [see here](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd/blob/v1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram/graphviz.rb#L198)

Can you edit the gem and print out the error message?

Comment: The path is here: c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-erd-1.1.0/lib/rails_erd/diagram/graphviz.rb, just edit that file

Comment: I am now getting following error after replacing the Gem file                                                               $ rake erd
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant RailsERD::Domain::Attribute::Inspectable

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on OS 10.9.2.

**Solution**

```
brew install graphviz
```

**Create erd - working on Rails 4**

```
erd --inheritance --direct --attributes=foreign_keys,content --filetype=dot
dot -Tjpg erd.dot > erd.jpg
```

You could also replace jpg with pdf

Answer (score 5):

**For Ubuntu users:**

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

**MacOS**

```
brew uninstall graphviz
brew install cairo
brew install pango
brew install graphviz
```

Comment: Yes, the order is significant, see [this github issue](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd/issues/8#issuecomment-898957)

Answer (score 0):

This could be as a result of no models in your rails application. Go to your app/model and make sure there are model files. If not, try to generate models and define their relationships.